# Laravel API Not Found

Tags: php, laravel, api

I'm trying to test my api and for this matter I don't need authentication for my api all I want to do is to share my published posts with api but I get `404` page.

## Code

`controller`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Post;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return Post::orderby('id', 'desc')->where('status', '=', '1')->get();
    }

    public function single($slug){
        return Post::where('slug', $slug)->where('status', '=', '1')->firstOrFail();
    }
}
```

`api.php` (routes folder)

```
Route::get('posts', 'API\PostController@index');
Route::get('posts/{slug}', 'API\PostController@single');
```

I tried to access my api posts with url like:  `http://newapp.test/api/posts` and it returns `404` error.

**Any idea?**

## Update

`api.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

// Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
//     return $request->user();
// });

Route::get('posts', 'API\PostController@index');
Route::get('posts/{slug}', 'API\PostController@single');
```

Comment: can you share full api.php file

Comment: @BhavinSolanki updated

Comment: Have you tried to call your api like : http://newapp.test/posts

Comment: @BhavinSolanki same result `404`

Comment: updated my answer : try `php artisan route:clear ` and check

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Leave all things as it is and **RUN Command**

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Answer (score 4):

Run command `php artisan route:list`. It will show you list of available routes in your application. In this way, you could first verify the existing routes and the ones you are trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

My API mistake was: **redirecting back**

```
if($validator->fails()){ return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('error',$validator->errors()->first());}
```

corrected by: **returning a JSON**

```
if($validator->fails()){ return $this->responseWithError($validator->errors()->first()); }
```

responseWithError is a helper method that returns JSON in a certain structure